Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D TextOut vs TextWidth units. Can't place text at the top right of the chart
I am using .Net c# version of Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D.TextOut to write text in a specific font at the top right corner.
Here is my code:
        text = "Some Text etc.";

        // Measure the width of the text
        int textWidth = (int) g.TextWidth(cf, text);

        // Calculate the starting X-coordinate to align text to the right
        int xPosition = _tChart.Right-textWidth;// (g.ChartXCenter * 2  - textWidth);

        // Set the Y-coordinate for the top of the chart
        int yPosition = 0; // Top of the chart

        // Draw the text at the calculated position
        g.TextOut(cf, xPosition, yPosition, text); 

It does not seem to place the text at the correct position.
If I specify a very short text like "0" it seems to be placed more or less at the right edge but longer text tends to show further left.
My other attempt was using
     int xPosition = (g.ChartXCenter * 2  - textWidth);

which looked better for longer text but would shift short text off the screen.
Difference between g.ChartXCenter*2 and _tChart.Right seems to be about margins etc according to documentation.
The real problem is that g.TextWidth seems to be not in the same units as TextOut. From what I could get out of very limited docs TextWidth is in pixels while TextOut is in 'screen coordinates' whatever that means.
My guess that it might be points vs pixels and adjusting textWidth by .75 did not resolve the issue.
